# State Not Updating As Expected Between Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, react-hooks

I have two inputs.

`Email Address`

`First Name`

On initial load, first name is hidden.

Clicking on the Email address input, will hide a div and show the first name input.
It will also hide a div above the inputs and the inputs will fill that space.

Now, the functionality I am looking for is after a user clicks the email address input, and then the user clicks the first name the first name should not disappear and the div to return.

To do so, at the moment, I have added a lodash debounce delay on the `onBlur` event listener to wait to see if a user focuses on the first name  input.

I have a state variable `onBlurWait` that defaults to `false` and gets updated to `true` when a user focuses on the first name input.

Focusing on the first name input, calls the `onBlur` event listener to check the value of the `onBlurWait` state. This listener for now, just returns a `console.log` or `onBlurWait`.

The `onBlur` on the email address input seems to get called before the `onFocus` of the first name input. So it seems that the `onBlurWait` state does not get updated so the `console.log` in the `onBlur` event listener will return false.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7qyxkn511?fontsize=14) that will help you play around with it, so you can hopefully understand what I am referencing above.

Below is my Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import InputControl from "./InputControl";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [hideContent, setHideContent] = useState(false);
  const [emailSignUpRef, setEmailSignUpRef] = useState(null);
  const [firstNameSignUpRef, setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef] = useState(null);
  const [onBlurWait, setOnBlurWait] = useState(false);

  let registerEmailInput = null;
  let firstNameInput = null;

  // If you click on email address then on first name, I would expect the console.log below to return true
  // due to when a user focuses on the first name input the handleInputFocus function gets called
  // inside that function, setOnBlurWait(true); is ran updating the value of onBlurWait to true
  // But it seems like it has not actually been updated
  // Now when you click on email address to first name, back to email address and first name again, the console log now returns true?
  const waitOnUpdateState = _.debounce(() => console.log(onBlurWait), 2000);
  const hideContentAfterState = _.debounce(
    () =>
      setHideContent(
        emailSignUpRef.length > 0 || firstNameSignUpRef.length > 0 || onBlurWait
      ),
    2000
  );

  const handleOnFocus = event => {
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
    setHideContent(true);
  };

  const handleOnInput = () => {
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
  };

  const handleInputFocus = () => {
    console.log("clicked on first name, onBlurWait should be set as true");
    setOnBlurWait(true);
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    console.log("clicked away from email address");
    // waitOnUpdateState is just a test function to return a console log, hideContentAfterState is what is going to be used
    waitOnUpdateState();
    hideContentAfterState();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={hideContent ? "hidden" : "visible"} />
      <InputControl
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          registerEmailInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="text"
        name="emailAddressRegister"
        placeholder="Email address"
        label="Email Address"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          firstNameInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onFocus={handleInputFocus}
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making it simpler, you are overthinking it.

`onFocus` and `onBlur` both receive `relatedTarget` as one of the properties in their [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events). In case of `onBlur`, `relatedTarget` is the DOM element [for which the focus is leaving](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) the `target`.

What you could do is handle the `blur` event and compare `relatedTarget` property of the event to the input refs. Then you will be able to figure out whether focus is leaving for another form element or some other DOM element on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when passing `event` as an argument onBlur, `event.relatedTarget` is being returned as `null`? I have updated the CodeSandbox so you can see

Comment: Actually, just realised it was `null` because I was clicking the body and not the element. Thanks again! Useful information :)